# How to transfer ERC20 Token using web3js

Tags: web3js, javascript, walletconnect

I am trying to send erc20 token using web3js version 1.6.1 but I am getting some strange error ,

I tried to copy the error from console and paste it in google but I could not find any results

**this is my code**

```
async sendToken() {
      let address = "0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef"; // BAT Token Contract Address
      let minABI = [
        {
          "constant": true,
          "inputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "address",
              "name": "account",
              "type": "address"
            }
          ],
          "name": "balanceOf",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "uint256",
              "name": "",
              "type": "uint256"
            }
          ],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "constant": false,
          "inputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "address",
              "name": "recipient",
              "type": "address"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "uint256",
              "name": "amount",
              "type": "uint256"
            }
          ],
          "name": "transfer",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "bool",
              "name": "",
              "type": "bool"
            }
          ],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "function"
        },

      ];
      let contract =new this.web3.eth.Contract(minABI,address);
      let decimals = this.web3.utils.toBN(18);
      let amount = this.web3.utils.toBN(10);
      let value = amount.mul(this.web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
      let toAddress="toAddress";
      contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, value).send({from: this.account})
          .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
            console.log(hash);
          })
    }
```

**this is Error in console**

```
Failed to launch 'wc:3d4f63f4-2359-48a0-acb6-ce2416956fe1@1' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.
```

Comment: The transfer code seems fine. The error message seems unrelated to the code. Did you get a hash? Did the operation fail?

Comment: @Ismael yes I found out this in not an error it is just an message and unrelated to code, but I could not solve yet, when I try to transfer i can not see transaction details in trust wallet please take a look to this screen shot، this is what happens when i try to transfer token https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NthJ.jpg

Comment: It seems to be a wallet limitation to not show the details.

Comment: Yes it seems trust issue, it works in metamask correctly, any idea how to fix it in trust wallet?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use Trust wallet.